# Nvidia driver for toshiba p850

Tags: nvidia

I have tried over and over installing the latest drive for my 630m on Ubuntu 12.04 but all it succeeds in doing is changing my resolution and I have to remove it again, the laptop came with both a chipset graphics and the gpu but will only recognise the chipset any advise?

Comment: type in the Terminal:

lspci -nn | grep VGA and put the results

Comment: Just tried but my resolution is so messed up can only see half the terminal

Comment: Ok got my resolution fixed again the command you gave has given me a list of options

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Just a list of options again

Comment: what are these options !!

Comment: UPDATE:LINK has been corrected
also, check this Question which asks about the 630M  : [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936)

Comment: Basic display mode

Comment: Display options, resolving of device IDs to names, selection of devices and the list goes on sorry I can't screen shot am having to do this from my phone

Answer (score 0):

Bumblebee Project: Bumblebee aims to provide support for NVIDIA **Optimus** laptops for GNU/Linux distribution

Check the wiki for a step by step to installation

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: I have followed the instructions on the bumblebee web site but after entering the last command line(sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia) I get the answer  E: unable to locate package bumblebee, E: unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia